# TypeORM adding empty/null values for a specific column

Tags: nestjs, typeorm, node.js-typeorm

The problem is sometimes a specific column becomes empty or null for no reason, the column is "link_status", follow the code bellow.

"typeorm": "^0.2.40"

```
useFactory: async () =>
  await createConnection({
    type: 'mysql',
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    port: 3306,
    username: process.env.DB_USER,
    password: process.env.DB_PASS,
    database: process.env.DB_DATABASE,
    entities: [Link, LinkPayment, LinkPaymentStatus, LinkItems],
    synchronize: true,
  }),
```

```
@Entity('link')
export class Link extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  link_id: number
  @Column()
  patient_id: number
  @Column({ length: 9 })
  link_status: string
  @Column({ length: 45 })
  token: string
  @Column({ length: 100 })
  link_url: string
  @Column()
  created_at: Date
  @Column()
  expiry_at: Date
  @Column()
  updated_at: Date
}
```

Comment: you're using `synchronize: true`, that's the reason. I don't know why it becomes empty or null, tbh

Comment: @MicaelLevi that's the problem, the synchronize doesn't do that to others columns only with him

Comment: it could be a bug. Typeorm have a lot of bugs :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is when I change my branch to a version which doesn't have the column in the entity and `synchronize` is `true` they turn all rows in this column Empty because that column doesn't exist.

A simple misunderstand in the configuration and usage...